# For base64 encoding/decoding, can base64 and uuencode/uudecode be used exchangeably?

Tags: base64

Do both `base64` (from coreutils) and `uuencode -m` and `uudecode` (from sharutils) implement base64 encoding and decoding? Can they be used exchangeably?

Comment: Try `man uuencode`, which will demonstrate that they're not synonymous.

Comment: I can't figure out if they are exchangeable as far as base64 encoding/decoding is concerned.

Comment: There are (at least) two different mappings for base64.  You'd have to read the source-code to be certain that they're the same.

Comment: "different mappings for base64", for example?

Comment: RFC 3548 and RFC 4648.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Being, as it is, that 4648 obsoletes 3548, there is only one valid base64 encoding. And being, as it is, that both use (in practice) the same wording for `section 4 base64` any difference should have been reported as a bug long time ago.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Could you provide a file example that doesn't encode the same in `uuencode -m` and `bas64` (beside the added header and footer of `uuencode`)?.

Answer (score 1):

Except for the header and tail that uuencode adds to its output, yes:

```
$ uuencode -m - <<<"Hello World! test"
begin-base64 644 -
SGVsbG8gV29ybGQhIHRlc3QK
====

$ base64 <<<"Hello World! test"
SGVsbG8gV29ybGQhIHRlc3QK
```

But `uuencode` is specified by posix, base64 no.